# Is Z-Buffering generally faster than the Painter's Algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, 3d

I am making a 3D renderer in Java from scratch with no external libraries. As I am trying to optimize I want to know a general/average answer whether the Painter's Algorithm is faster than Z-Buffering. Say if I was rendering one cube that was the same which would be faster. But I don't want intersecting polygons to mess up so I probably want to implement Newell's edition of the Painter's Algorithm that cuts the polygons so they don't intersect and mess up.

So can I have an order of what would averagely be faster rendering a single cube:

[Painter's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm)

[Newell's Painter's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newell%27s_algorithm)

[Z-Buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering)

Also if anyone has any other good suggestions I could possibly use?

Comment: It's stupid how I ask this like 20 minutes ago and it's already 8 pages down on the "Newest"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In computer graphics the painter's algorithm is called `Z-Sorting`**

sometimes it is faster sometimes not. It depends on how many objects you have, how big is the resolution you are rendering and what precision of `Z` coordinate you need.

**`Z-Buffering` is better for:**

- high object/polygon count
- dynamic scene (objects or camera are moving/rotating)

  it needs additional buffer in the same resolution as rendered image and it performs single condition per fragment (rendered pixel of each polygon even unseen ones). After render the **3D** `z` coordinate of each visible pixel is at disposal which is required for many advanced rendering techniques.

**`Z-Sorting` is better for:**

- (relatively) static scenes or very low object/polygon count
- if very little memory is at disposal (on 8bit computers most **3D** apps used `Z-sorting` because there was no memory for `Z-buffer`)

  it need index buffer to store all the object/polygon indexes and it performs sorting on each scene change (sorting many objects by Z coordinate can be slow). Nowadays it is used because of:
- transparent polygons need Z-sorting
- if program already have Z sorted scene for some other reason so it take advantage of it

**Sometimes these two techniques are combined together**

especially for high dynamic range of `Z` coordinate because standard Z-buffers (24/32 bit wide) have very poor resolution on the whole range. It can be partially solved by use of linear or logarithmic scale of `Z-buffer` but if you need defined accuracy/resolution on the full range you need to use some kind of combination with Z-sorting and combine more **frustrums** together or use custom `Z-Buffer` with high dynamic range which is not supported by current **HW**

Comment: Thank you for the question.